# Remove and adding elements to array in GO lang

Tags: arrays, go, append, slice

I have 2 arrays declared as : 
`var input []string` and `var output []string` .

The input array is filled with some IDs initially. Output array is NULL.

After every iteration I want to remove a random element from input array and add it to output array.

At the end all the elements in output array will be same as input array (but with different ordering(indexing)).

```
for index := 0; index < len(input); index++ {
    if !visited[index] {
        //do something
    }
}
output[#iteration index] = input[current index]
```

When I try to do this, I get `array out of bounds error`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For the `output` array you need to use `append` or allocate it with an initial capacity to match the size of `input`.

```
// before the loop
output := make([]string, len(input))
```

would be my recommendation because `append` causes a bunch of needless reallocations and you already know what capacity you need since it's based on the `input`.

The other thing would be:

```
output = append(output, input[index])
```

But like I said, from what I've observed append grows the initial capacity exponentially. This will be base 2 if you haven't specified anything which means you're going to be doing several unneeded reallocations before reaching the desired capacity.

Comment: Is there a way to append to a slice without reassigning it?

Answer (score 47):

You could find some useful tricks at [golang/SliceTricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks).

Since the introduction of the `append` built-in, most of the functionality of the `container/vector` package, which was removed in Go 1, can be replicated using `append` and `copy`.

Here are the vector methods and their slice-manipulation analogues:

AppendVector

```
a = append(a, b...)
```

Copy

```
b = make([]T, len(a))
copy(b, a)
// or
b = append([]T(nil), a...)
```

Cut

```
a = append(a[:i], a[j:]...)
```

Delete

```
a = append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...)
// or
a = a[:i+copy(a[i:], a[i+1:])]
```

Delete without preserving order

```
a[i] = a[len(a)-1] 
a = a[:len(a)-1]
```

**NOTE** If the type of the element is a *pointer* or a struct with pointer fields, which need to be garbage collected, the above implementations of `Cut` and `Delete` have a potential *memory leak* problem: some elements with values are still referenced by slice `a` and thus can not be collected. The following code can fix this problem:

> **Cut**

```
copy(a[i:], a[j:])
for k, n := len(a)-j+i, len(a); k < n; k++ {
    a[k] = nil // or the zero value of T
}
a = a[:len(a)-j+i]
```

> **Delete**

```
copy(a[i:], a[i+1:])
a[len(a)-1] = nil // or the zero value of T
a = a[:len(a)-1]
```

> **Delete without preserving order**

```
a[i] = a[len(a)-1]
a[len(a)-1] = nil
a = a[:len(a)-1]
```

Expand

```
a = append(a[:i], append(make([]T, j), a[i:]...)...)
```

Extend

```
a = append(a, make([]T, j)...)
```

Insert

```
a = append(a[:i], append([]T{x}, a[i:]...)...)
```

**NOTE** The second `append` creates a new slice with its own underlying storage and  copies elements in `a[i:]` to that slice, and these elements are then copied back to slice `a` (by the first `append`). The creation of the new slice (and thus memory garbage) and the second copy can be avoided by using an alternative way:

> **Insert**

```
s = append(s, 0)
copy(s[i+1:], s[i:])
s[i] = x
```

InsertVector

```
a = append(a[:i], append(b, a[i:]...)...)
```

Pop

```
x, a = a[0], a[1:]
```

Pop Back

```
x, a = a[len(a)-1], a[:len(a)-1]
```

Push

```
a = append(a, x)
```

Push Front

```
a = append([]T{ x }, a...)
```

Shift

```
x, a := a[0], a[1:]
```

Unshift

```
a = append([]T{x}, a...)
```

### Additional Tricks

#### Filtering without allocating

This trick uses the fact that a slice shares the same backing array and capacity as the original, so the storage is reused for the filtered slice. Of course, the original contents are modified.

```
b := a[:0]
for _, x := range a {
    if f(x) {
        b = append(b, x)
    }
}
```

#### Reversing

To replace the contents of a slice with the same elements but in reverse order:

```
for i := len(a)/2-1; i >= 0; i-- {
    opp := len(a)-1-i
    a[i], a[opp] = a[opp], a[i]
}
```

The same thing, except with two indices:

```
for left, right := 0, len(a)-1; left < right; left, right = left+1, right-1 {
    a[left], a[right] = a[right], a[left]
}
```

#### Shuffling

Fisher–Yates algorithm:

```
for i := len(a) - 1; i > 0; i-- {
    j := rand.Intn(i + 1)
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
}
```

Comment: I have an array of struct's with two properties (ex.  [{ "prop1": 1, "prop2": 2 }, { "prop1": 1, "prop2": 2 }] etc.  I want to create a new array of int's for prop1 only from this existing array - whats the best way to do that? (can you add an example possibly?)

Answer (score 2):

In Go 1.21, [Insert](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Insert), [Delete](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Delete) (and more!) functions are available for Slice

### Example

#### Insert

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

func main() {
    names := []string{"Alice", "Bob", "Vera"}
    names = slices.Insert(names, 1, "Bill", "Billie")
    names = slices.Insert(names, len(names), "Zac")
    fmt.Println(names)
}
```

#### Delete

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

func main() {
    letters := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
    letters = slices.Delete(letters, 1, 4)
    fmt.Println(letters)
}
```